# Express.js - cast interface by body inside request object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I written a similar ground to ASP.NET MVC structure and I released on my github ([express-mvc](https://github.com/afulsamet/express-mvc)). Everything is ok but I can't cast `body` inside the `request` object to fit any interface.

This is exactly what I want:

```js
export default interface Post {
    title: string
    body: string
}
```

```js
import Post from '@models/user'

router.post("/post", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const Model: Post = req.body
})
```

but didnt work interface on runtime because no interface on JavaScript. When I use this, will be output in JavaScript

```
const Model;
Model = req.body
```

When it's that way, it assignment non-members property of interface to my variable.

In short, I want known properties of interface in `Model` variable.

I'm using destructuring to solve the problem temporarily in this project

```js
import Post from '@models/user'

router.post("/post", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { title, body }: Post = req.body

    const Model: Post = <Post>{
        title,
        body
    };
})
```

Do you have any suggestions

---

#### Solve problem with classes

```js
function castByBody<Model>(source: {}, modelProperties: any[]): Partial<Model> {
    const post: Partial<Model> = {};
    for (const key of modelProperties) {
        post[key] = source[key];
    }
    return post;
}

class User {
  public first_name: string = null
  public username: string = null
  public email: string = null
  public password: string = null
  public age: number = null
}

let user = new User() // create new instance
let userProperties: any[] = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(user) // get all properties from instance

const reqBody = { 
  first_name: "afulsamet",
  username: "aful",
  email: "afulsamet@gmail.com",
  password: "333222233",
  title: "member", 
  age: 18 
} // user instance does not have title property

const model: Partial<User> = castByBody<User>(reqBody, userProperties);

console.log(model)
```

Output will be as in console

```
{
  age: 18
  email: "afulsamet@gmail.com"
  first_name: "afulsamet"
  password: "333222233"
  username: "aful"
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false#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-f5KiICdMQ2HwlMAZgbACZm42G1XLLAoGSUxs8dJ4wGcljNgBGAAcg+4iCZFLGPKgfI5+DgciOcCiAAsUAA3DmdslWtIybCuswRJ1RITubPaXSuEbSLzIdBYXAEYgPph0L0+7D8I1amKmS1G6TpwGSSqUHAey0FeVDqEAA)

Comment: Please don't **boldface** every **third** **word** of your **question**. It makes **it** very hard **to** read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When it's that way, it assignment non-members property of interface to my variable.

If you don't want that, then you can't using casting (it's not really casting, in TypeScript it's called *type assertion*). You do have to create a new object.

You can do that with destructuring as you have, although you can make it feel a bit less clunky by doing it sooner (in the parameter list), and you don't need a type assertion on it, TypeScript will see that what you're assigning is acceptable:

```
router.post("/post", ({body: { title, body }}, res: Response) => {
    const Model: Post = {
        title,
        body
    };
})
```

Doing that automatically (without having to type `title` and `body`) based on the type information would require TypeScript to provide runtime type information, which is [currently outside TypeScript's goals](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1549) (though it's a commonly-requested feature).

Of course, it doesn't have to be destructuring. You could have an array of your property names (the thing TypeScript won't give you), probably defined right alongside the type, and use that instead:

```
const PostKeys = ["title", "body"];
```

then

```
router.post("/post", ({body}, res: Response) => {
    const Model: {} as Post;
    for (const key of PostKeys) {
        Model[key] = body[key];
    }
})
```

perhaps even make it a reusable function

```
function createPost(source: any): Post {
    const post: {} as Post;
    for (const key of PostKeys) {
        post[key] = source[key];
    }
    return post;
}
```

then

```
router.post("/post", ({body}, res: Response) => {
    const Model: createPost(body);
})
```

Comment: Destructuring, There will be no problem in interface with several property. What if we have too many properties to write one by one? That's not good at all.

Comment: @AbdulsametKurt - As far as I know, you basically have two choices: A type assertion on `req.body` (knowing that it will have properties that aren't described by its type), or listing those properties in a runtime-accessible way (probably just once in an array somewhere) and loop over that list of properties. If there were one runtime type feature I'd like to see in TypeScript, it would be something like `const MyTypeKeys = keyof MyType;` as a runtime construct. But AFAIK it does not exist.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I've researched this problem a lot, and I've usually heard that "This remains outside our design goals" but I'm sure there is a way to achieve this. Do you have another any suggestions?

Comment: When I look at new solution, it will seems to work. Thanks

Comment: @AbdulsametKurt - I'm fairly sure there isn't at present, but before my previous comment I pinged someone who knows TS much better than I do for a second opinion. :-) He'll probably comment (or answer) in the next few hours.

Comment: @AbdulsametKurt - Just FWIW, the [guy I pinged](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir), who knows TypeScript really well, confirmed that TypeScript doesn't have a better way to do this.

Comment: I got a chance to look at your comment ATM and thank you for your help. I have one more another question. I want to get properties of interface as Array without [ts-transformer-keys](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys) module. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @AbdulsametKurt - As far as I know, no, which is pretty much what I said in the answer above. Presumably that *why* `ts-transformer-keys` exists (handy tool, that).